# Meaning of "foi de"

Tags: sens

I am reading the Tintin book "Les Cigares du pharaon".
On page 5, in the last picture, Dupond says:

> Foi de Dupond, il ne courra pas longtemps!

Dupont then replies:

> Je dirais même plus: il ne courra pas longtemps, foi de Dupont!

I know that 'foi' means 'faith', but what does 'foi de [oneself]' mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in a dictionary, the TLFi;

> Jurer sa foi, sur sa foi, par sa foi. Affirmer sous serment. Menteur! il m'a juré sa foi, et il y avait des témoins (AYMÉ, Vogue, 1944, p. 69). Ma foi, par ma foi, sur ma foi, foi de (gentilhomme, honnête homme, etc.). Je le jure, j'en donne ma parole. Tiens, vois-tu, maintenant, foi d'homme, je suis fâché de t'avoir battue (SUE, Myst. Paris, t. 1, 1842, p. 64). Cléopâtre fut moins aimée, oui, sur ma foi! (VERLAINE, Œuvres compl., t. 1, Fêtes gal., 1869, p. 93).

When someone says "foi de X", that is done to swear that what he or she says is true.

Here you would translate (in basic English) as follows;

- I swear it, he won't be running much longer!

Answer (score 0):

Foi means "faith", so in this context both character says that you can have faith in them that a certain person will not run for long.

"Have faith on me, he is not gonna run for long"

"I'll say even more, he is not gonna run for long, have faith in me" or "faith in Dupont"

Answer (score 0):

Nos deux compères sont bien connus pour être des gens peux fiables et fort peu efficaces.

*Par ma foi* était à ses origines un juron (au même titre que *Par Dieu*) de grande valeur aux temps où les chevaliers combattaient pour elle.

Il est par suite attaché aux promesses faites / engagements / serments pris par les gentilshommes qui juraient donc *... par ma foi* ou *foi de gentilhomme*

L'amusant dans tout cela est que... les gentilshommes ne se souciaient que peu des promesses faites au vilain ce qui donna lieu au proverbe : *Foi de gentilhomme, un autre gage vaut mieux!"*

Sachant la réputation de fiabilité des deux Dupontd... la garantie de bonne fin de leurs actions... Il est probable qu'Hergé ait eu ce dicton en tête afin de renforcer le coté... *bidon* du propos de ses deux matamores.